# Send an email through Sharepoint workflow one week before a date

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I need a workflow to track a due date on an issues list and one week before due date send a reminder email.

My workflow is

Add -7 days to CurrentItem:DueDate (Output to Variable:date1)

then pause until Variable:Date1

then email CurrentItem:Responsible

with the email being sent to

CurrentItem:Responsible returned as an email address, semicolon delimited.

This currently isn't emailing my user, but the workflow is completing after the seven day point is reached.

Is there a better way to set up this workflow, or why might this workflow complete but not send the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of things can go wrong with mailing from WF.

I would check if the SharePoint-User you have selected actually has an email (and the right one) assigned in SP.

Eventually you can write the mail-address to the log, after the pause, so you really can see if the WF finds it.

Answer (score -1):

In this blog, you can write the mail-address to the log,

Declare due date =29/02/2016 & minus 7 days stored in date variable

This remainder mail through users or author of the item,

Site workflow has been created .we ll run this action site level

[Please click Here](http://peakfinders.blogspot.in/2016/02/before-days-send-reminder-mail.html)